# Using a variable in sqlalchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to form a query in sqlalchemy but not sure how I can achieve this. I want to be able to use the variable in my query

```
 dog_type = 'pug'
 dog_name = 'buddy'
 .filter (animal.dogs.pug == 'buddy')
```

This is what I want it to be like:

```
.filter (animal.dogs.<dog_type> == <dog_name>)
```

While researching a bit about this I found some ways to do a similar thing.

1. Using kwargs as filter parameter
2. using getattr like this:

   ```
   .filter(getattr(animal, dogs) == 'buddy')
   ```

however both the options don't seem to be working for my case or atleast for what I have tried. So any suggestion how could do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how filter works. first define a model:

```
class Dog(Base):
    __tablename__ = "dogs"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

then import this class in your code:

```
import Dog
```

then you can query it like this:

```
pugs = db_session.query(Dog).filter(Dog.name == "pug").all()

for pug in pugs:
    print("I'm a pug in the database! I have ID " + str(pug.id))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am actually working on some pre-existing code and I don't want to change the structure of it. Is there no way I can do something like `animal.dogs.<dog_type> == <dog_name>` without having to make any changes to the class and objects? Also the query that I am currently running is working fine but I want to be able to use variable in the query instead.

Comment: Please post your full data model, then I can try to help you. I cannot guess what animal and dog is before seeing classes or instances that define them.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution to my problem. Nesting getattr solved the problem.

```
animal_type = 'dogs'
dog_type = 'pug'
dog_name = 'buddy'
.filter(getattr(getattr(animal, animal_type), dog_type) == dog_name)
```